# I have faced and issue when i run app by using command "flutter run" please help me to fix it?

Tags: java, flutter, dart

error: incompatible types: MainActivity cannot be converted to FlutterEngine
GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this);

Comment: Have you tried putting the error into a search engine? https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/65630 https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/58347 If those do not help, please update this question with more details, such as the relevant parts of your code.

Comment: here is error : MainActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
* Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.